# How to display a more "zoomed out" background image

Tags: jquery, css, svg

so I'm designing a photo frame designer you can find [here](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame2) if interested. It is built using SVG. On it I have it so that when a pattern is clicked on the frame editor, the text in the visual representation of the frame will change so that it's background is the same as the one selected. However, the patterns seem sort of "zoomed in". I want it to show something like [this](http://dunnrite.co.uk/Images/screenshot.png). Here is some code that could be helpful.

```
<text class="text" transform="matrix(2.4428 0 0 1.5 624.6 550.5599)" font-family="'ComicSansMS'" font-size="41.6368">Your words here</text>

    $("#pattern1").click (function() {
    $('.text').css('-webkit-background-size', 'cover');
    $('.text').css('background-size', 'cover');
    $('.text').css('-moz-background-size', 'cover');
    $('.text').css('-o-background-size', 'cover');
    $('.text').css('fill', 'url(#patt1)');
});
```

Comment: Can you make a JS Fiddle instead?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5dnco1v6/

Comment: i dont think the fiddle works. You may have to go off inspect element in the website.

Comment: lots of bugs in your HTML, e.g. no `<head>`, use of `width` attribute but with units (use CSS instead), use consecutive `<br>` to adjust layout etc. Also, JSFiddle has its own jQuery. no need to attach another version to it

Comment: That's just on the fiddle... As they have that sorted. No units is because it's SVG. Html doesn't work with svg.